Given date in Gregorian, convert to localedate
mwe.tex:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% -- Babel setup
\usepackage[
    english,
    bidi=basic,
    layout=counters tabular
]{babel}
\babelprovide[
    import, main,
    justification = kashida,
    calendar=islamic-civil,
    transforms = kashida.plain
]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{ScheherazadeNew}

\title{title}
\date{\localedate[calendar=gregorian]{2024}{07}{21}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
\end{document}

This renders 2024-07-21 as a localized Gregorian date.
How can I render 2024-07-21 as a localized Hijri date? Can Babel do date conversions?
If \date isn't specified, Babel assumes \today and it shows the Hijri date of today (Note the calendar=islamic-civil option), so I assume Babel has a basic way of converting dates.
My goal:

Input is 2024-07-21 (Gregorian).
Convert to 1445-01-15 (Hijri)
Localize and render as "14 محرم، 1446"


The \date? What do you mean? Please show us your use-case in a document. Refer to section 1.19 of the babel manual where it showa how to use \localdate (and how \today is convertes automatically).

Please, provide a MWE showing what you have attempted.

@Qrrbrbirlbel \date the date of the \maketitle.

If I’ve understood correctly, what you want is \localedate[convert]{2024}{07}{21}.

Yes. Thank you. Is the reverse conversion possible? Given a date in locale, convert it back to Gregorian?

Nope, babel isn't a general date converter. Its only purpose is to generate correctly the current date in the way users would expect in their own culture. For this reason, the range in calendars like islamic-umalqura and chinese is restricted to a few decades, too.

The option calendar sets the target calendar, so with calendar=gregorian you are requesting the gregorian one. Since you have set islamic-civil as the default calendar for arabic, there are to options:
1)
\localedate{1445}{01}{15}

No conversion, so year, month and day are in the target calendar.
2)
\localedate[convert]{2024}{07}{01}

Convert year, month, and day from gregorian to the target calendar.
There is a real need for the latter, because tex only provides the gregorian calendar, so some kind of conversion is required to generate correctly the current date in the way users would expect in their own culture. It’s not a general purpose calendar converter.
